# Hacer un programa que lea una matriz y sume sus elementos

Tags: c, revisión-de-código

A mi hermano le mandaron hacer el ejercicio mencionado en el titulo, el lo hizo pero no le sale la suma, sino que solo le devuelve los datos ingresados;

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAXFIL 20
#define MAXCOL 30

void leermatriz( int a[][MAXCOL], int nfilas, int ncols );
void sumamatriz( int a[][MAXCOL], int nfilas, int ncols );
void resultado( int a[][MAXCOL], int nfilas, int ncols );

main( ) {
  int nfilas, ncols;
  int a[MAXFIL][MAXCOL];

  printf( "\ncantidad de filas de la matriz" );
  scanf( "\n%d", &nfilas );
  printf( "\ncantidad de columnas de la matriz" );
  scanf( "\n%d", &ncols );
  printf( "\ndigite la matriz" );

  leermatriz( a, nfilas, ncols );
  sumamatriz( a, nfilas, ncols );
  printf( "\n\nsumas todos sus elementos:\n\n" );
  resultado( a, nfilas, ncols );
}

void leermatriz( int a[][MAXCOL], int m, int n ) {
  int fila, col;

  for( fila=0; fila <m; ++fila ) {
    printf( "\ndatos de fila n° %2d\n", fila + 1 );
    for( col=0; col<n; ++col ) {
      printf( "\nlos elementos %2d\n", col + 1 );
      scanf( "%d", &a[fila][col] );
    }
  }

  return;
}

void sumamatriz( int a[][MAXCOL],int m, int n ) {
  int fila, col;

  for(fila=0; fila<m; ++fila)
    for(col=0; col<n; ++col)
      a[fila][col];

  return;
}

void resultado( int a[][MAXCOL], int m, int n ) {
  int fila, col;

  for( fila = 0; fila < m; ++fila ) {
    for( col=0; col<n; ++col )
      printf( "%4d", a[fila][col] );

    printf( "\n" );
  }

  return;
}
```

Paso buena parte intentando encontrar la falla y al final no pudo, agradecería si me pudieren decir que es lo que tiene malo para que no le de el resultado deseado (sumar correctamente en una matriz)

Comment: ¿ Donde está exactamente la operación de suma ? Porque yo no la veo por ningún lado. ¿ Hay algún error al transcribir el código ?

Answer (score 1):

El error está acá:

```
void sumamatriz( int a[][MAXCOL],int m, int n ) {
  int fila, col;

  for(fila=0; fila<m; ++fila)
    for(col=0; col<n; ++col)
      a[fila][col];

  return;
}
```

Obviando el hecho de que eso no suma nada y que además, esa función no hace nada y está mal por dónde se vea.

Como es una función void, sin retorno, no va:

```
return;
```

Y, en el caso de que la función retornara algo tendría que ser algo como:

```
return algo;
```

Los dos bucles for y esa cosa de `a[fila][col]` es completamente inútil, es decir, creo que tienen que volver a pensar el problema, primero resolverlo en alguna especie de pseudocódigo y luego pasarlo a C, porque si no se entiende a lo que se quiere llegar, no se puede empezar a programar.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu codigo veo que no estas sumando y acumulando tu variable. Imaginate que tienes una matriz [1 2 ; 2 3], para sumarla tienes que hacer (en notacion indicial)

*m11 + m12 + m21 + m22 = suma*

Si revisas el codigo de tu función `a[fila][col];` y lo mismo sucede en la sentencia `return;` donde no estas retornando ningun valor.

Tomando tu codigo simplemente te falta ir sumando y acumulando:

```
int suma = 0; //variable donde acumularemos, NO OLVIDAR INICIALIZAR EN CERO
//para no obtener valores raros o inesperados
for(fila=0; fila<m; ++fila)
{
for(col=0; col<n; ++col)
  {
    suma = suma + a[fila][col];
  }
}
```

Una recomendacion, usa las { } en la definicion de los bucles, por mas que tengas una sola sentencia, ayuda a que el code sea mas lindo y legible.
Muchas suerte!